# How to distinguish client and peer certificate generated by `cryptogen` in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have generated certificates with `cryptogen`.

And inspected generated certificates with `openssl` and noticed that it lacks information that can be used to distinguish peer and client roles. I believe `admin` can be distinguished because admincerts are written in blockchain, but there's no information about client and peers.

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = test.com, CN = ca.test.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep 19 01:49:00 2019 GMT
            Not After : Sep 16 01:49:00 2029 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, CN = User1@test.com
...
```

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = test.com, CN = ca.test.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep 19 01:49:00 2019 GMT
            Not After : Sep 16 01:49:00 2029 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, CN = p0.test.com
...
```

(Only differences I'm seeing is subject's CN, key and ID related things)

The reason I'm wondering this is, while their roles cannot be distinguished, an endorsing node setup with client's MSP won't work, because of CSCC failure when joining channel.

```
Error: proposal failed (err: bad proposal response 500: access denied for [JoinChain][testc]: [Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [This identity is not an admin]])
```

(other peers with it's MSP succeeded to join channel btw)

So the role system is working as intended, but how did CSCC actually get to know the certificate role? Is there a hidden mechanism?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer is based on Fabric 1.4.3 and later.

The specific error you are seeing means that you are not invoking the JoinChannel API using an identity (key/cert pair) which is considered to be an admin for the peer.  Prior to 1.4.3, admins were defined by explicitly putting certs in the *admincerts* folder in the local MSP directory of your peer(s).  In 1.4.3 and later, you can also enable admins to be identified via a specific *OU* in the Common Name (see below for more details).

So you need to invoke the JoinChannel API with a peer admin.  When using *cryptogen*, an admin user is created in the *users* directory.  You should use this identity when invoking JoinChannel.

**Details on MSP roles and how they are defined:**

There are 5 possible roles:

- admin
- peer
- client
- orderer
- member

In order to use the peer, client and orderer roles, you need to enable the ["identity classification" feature](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/msp.html#identity-classification).  When using the folder-based MSP structure, this is accomplished by setting enabling "NodeOUs" in the *config.yaml* file in the root of the MSP directory:

```
NodeOUs:
  Enable: true
  ClientOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca.sampleorg-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: client
  PeerOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca.sampleorg-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: peer
  AdminOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca.sampleorg-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: admin
  OrdererOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca.sampleorg-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: orderer
```

This defines how to distinguish MSP roles by *OU* present in the CommonName attribute of the X509 certificate.  The example above says that any certificate issued by *cacerts/ca.sampleorg-cert.pem* which has *OU=client* will identified as a client, *OU=peer* as a peer, etc.  As of 1.4.3, there is also an OU for admins so you no longer have to explicitly place certs in the *admincerts* folder of the MSP directory.

When using *cryptogen*, you can enable this feature by setting *EnableNodeOUs* to true in your *crypto-config.yaml* file and running *cryptogen generate --config crypto-config.yaml*.  For example, this will enabled NodeOUs for a peer org:

```
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: org1
    Domain: org1.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 2
      SANS:
         - "localhost"
         - "127.0.0.1"
         - "{{.Hostname}}-{{.Domain}}"
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Its is very straight forward, nothing much complex or hidden mechanism, its a PKI as you know.

Every entity peer, orderer has its own MSP

so what is present in the MSP

```
.
├── admincerts
├── cacerts
├── keystore
├── signcerts
└── tlscacerts
```

as you see every peer will generate trust because of local MSP, above structure of peer MSP we have **admincerts**, so whichever identity we mention peer will assume that identity as the admin and you need to sign the create channel, join channel or install chaincode **transaction** with that admin credentials,

if you change the credential peer will complain.

Same way **cacerts**: peer will assume whatever rootCA cert chain present in the cacerts folder it will accept any request from the client with identity issued by that ca

**Coming to your client and peers**:

hey while registering an identity you will mention role this is in the form of **attribute** which is used for many use cases you will get more insights when you generate certificates using **fabric-ca** rather than cryptogen tool

check [this](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#registering-a-new-identity)

Answer (score 0):

admin's certificate is stored in `admincerts` directory of `msp`. If a signature of a transaction can be verified by it, we can say that the sender of the transaction is `admincerts`. In short, fabric gets to know the certificate role from not certificate itself but msp.

Answer (score -1):

This is some thing which hyperledger fabric platform handle by its self. we just need to handle client certificate hyperledger fabric support attribute based certificate. so you can identify different certificate via their attribute.

in Fabric network each component has its own identity. which means each component has it own certificate which fabric handle by its self.